# How fast is Ruby's method for converting a range to an array?

Tags: ruby

`(1..999).to_a`

Is this method O(n)? I'm wondering if the conversion involves an implicit iteration so Ruby can write the values one-by-one into consecutive memory addresses.

Comment: That depends on what your n is. It does (end-start )/step writes, although it probably only does one allocation for the array

Comment: Don't try to convert ranges to arrays; It's very easy to create one that exceeds memory and/or will take Ruby to a crawl. Instead, iterate over the range.

Comment: @theTinMan A 1000 element array is insignificantly tiny on a normal computer. I definitely wouldn't recommend converting ranges to arrays in general, but there's no harm to doing it as long as you understand what's happening.

Comment: Yes, understanding the issues is the important thing. We have questions on SO from people who didn't know and killed their programs by trying to convert a range to millions of array elements. Most of the time iterating over the range will allow us to do the same thing as iterating over an array without the scalability issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The method](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/enum.c#L542-L550) is actually slightly worse than O(n). Not only does it do a naive iteration, but it doesn't check ahead of time what the size will be, so it has to repeatedly allocate more memory as it iterates. [I've opened an issue for that aspect](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/pull/444) and it's been discussed a few times on the mailing list (and briefly added to ruby-core). The problem is that, like almost anything in Ruby, Range can be opened up and messed with, so Ruby can't really optimize the method. It can't even count on `Range#size` returning the correct result. Worse, some enumerables even have their `size` method delegate to `to_a`.

In general, it shouldn't be necessary to make this conversion, but if you really need array methods, you might be able to use [Array#fill](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-fill) instead, which lets you populate a (potentially pre-allocated) array using values derived from its indices.

Comment: Right. `Range` gets `to_a` from `Enumerable` and `Enumerable#to_a` does it the easy way. There is no optimized `to_a` in `Range` unlike the `Array`-specific implementations of a lot of `Enumerable` methods that `Array` has.

Comment: The `Range` protocol is really simple: the only thing required from the endpoints is that they must respond to `<=>` and the left endpoint must respond to `succ`. That's it. That's all the `Range` knows about its two endpoints. There's really not much it can do than repeatedly call `succ` to enumerate all elements and push them into an `Array`. It simply doesn't know enough about its endpoints to do anything else. And that is by design: by adding more requirements you limit the choice of objects usable as range endpoints, and thus limit the genericity  and thus applicability of `Range`s.

Answer (score 2):

```
Range.instance_methods(false).include? :to_a
# false
```

Range doesn't have `to_a`, it inherits it from the `Enumerable` mix-in, so it builds the array by pushing each value on one at a time. That seems like it would be really inefficient, but I'll let the benchmark speak for itself:

```
require 'benchmark'

size = 100_000_000

Benchmark.bmbm do |r|
  r.report("range") { (0...size).to_a }
  r.report("fill") { a = Array.new(size); a.fill { |i| i } }
  r.report("array") { Array.new(size) { |i| i } }
end

# Rehearsal -----------------------------------------
# range   4.530000   0.180000   4.710000 (  4.716628)
# fill    5.810000   0.150000   5.960000 (  5.966710)
# array   7.630000   0.250000   7.880000 (  7.879940)
# ------------------------------- total: 18.550000sec
#
#             user     system      total        real
# range   4.540000   0.120000   4.660000 (  4.660249)
# fill    5.980000   0.110000   6.090000 (  6.089962)
# array   7.880000   0.110000   7.990000 (  7.985818)
```

Isn't that weird? It's actually the fastest by a significant margin. And manually filling an Array is somehow faster that just using the constructor.

But as is usually the case with Ruby, don't worry too much about this. For reasonably sized ranges the performance difference will be negligible.